# recognize misaligned pictures of handwritten digits with CNN

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to make a program that recognizes handwritten digits (from MNIST). I've actually done it and it works quite good. (I made a CNN that reaches 98% of accuracy on the test dataset)

Then I created a program where you could write the digits with your mouse and the computer said which digit you had written. When you write the digits in the middle of the screen, it works good, but when you write almost the same thing but a little bit misaligned, it doesn't work anymore. Is there a special cnn architecture for that? I tried several architecture but it's always the same. Maybe the problem is in the training data? --> because all the the digits are written in the middle of the picture.

Comment: Have you tried preprocessing the input drawing data in some way (eg. trimming the blank spaces beforehand, if you're only trying to recognize one digit)? That way your input written digit will always be in the "middle".

Comment: That's a great idea! I'm gonna try to do it